# Preserving Indexed comparisons between two list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
{{Subscript[i,  1], Subscript[a,  1], Subscript[b,  1]},
 {Subscript[i,  1], Subscript[a,  2], Subscript[b,  2]},
 ...,
 {Subscript[i,  r], Subscript[b,  1], Subscript[a,  1]},
 ...,
 {Subscript[i,  s], Subscript[b,  2], Subscript[a,  2]},
 ...,
 {Subscript[i,  n], Subscript[a,  n], Subscript[b,  n]}
}
```

in other words; this is a list indexed by:

```
{Subscript[i, 1], Subscript[i, 2], ..., Subscript[i, n]}
```

and every now and then; there are instances in the list where:
`{Subscript[a, i], Subscript[b, i]}`
is considered the same as:
`{Subscript[b, i], Subscript[a, i]}`.

For example; if two jobs contained in the above list; namely,

```
{"Bill and Account Collectors", "Ticket Agents and Travel Clerks"}
```

have a job relational score of  0.5; then

```
{"Ticket Agents and Travel Clerks", "Bill and Account Collectors"}
```

also have the same relational score.

My question is; how can I collapse  the above list to get a new list so
that; if

```
{Subscript[a, i], Subscript[b, i]} == {Subscript[b, i], Subscript[a, i]}
```

then only

```
{Subscript[i, s], {Subscript[a, i], Subscript[b, i]}}
```

is included in my new list; and if:

```
{Subscript[a, k], Subscript[b, k]} not equal {Subscript[b, k], Subscript[a, k]}
```

then both:

```
{Subscript[i, s], {Subscript[a, k], Subscript[b, k]}}
```

and

```
{Subscript[i, t], {Subscript[a, k], Subscript[b, k]}}
```

are also included in my new list?

As an example, if

```
IndexedSOCList = {{1., 431011., 431011.}, {2., 431011., 433011.}, {3., 433011., 431011.},
   {4., 431011., 433021.}, {5., 433021., 431011.}, {6., 431011., 433031.},
   {7., 433031., 431011.}, {8., 431011., 433051.}, {9., 433051., 431011.},
   {10., 431011., 433061.}, {11., 433061., 431011.}, {12., 431011., 433071.},
   {13., 433071., 431011.}, {14., 431011., 434011.}, {15., 434011., 431011.},
   {16., 431011., 434031.}, {17., 434031., 431011.}, {18., 431011., 434041.},
   {19., 434041., 431011.}};
```

then the desired output is

```
(* {{1., 431011., 431011.}, {2., 431011., 433011.}, {4., 431011., 433021.},
    {6., 431011., 433031.}, {8., 431011., 433051.}, {10., 431011., 433061.},
    {12., 431011., 433071.}, {14., 431011., 434011.}, {16., 431011., 434031.},
    {18., 431011., 434041.}} *)
```

Comment: One possibility, I think? `Union[list, SameTest -> (Sort[#1[[2]]] === Sort[#2[[2]]] &)]`.

Comment: IndexedSOCList={{1., 431011., 431011.}, {2., 431011., 433011.}, {3., 433011., 
  431011.}, {4., 431011., 433021.}, {5., 433021., 431011.}, {6., 
  431011., 433031.}, {7., 433031., 431011.}, {8., 431011., 
  433051.}, {9., 433051., 431011.}, {10., 431011., 433061.}, {11., 
  433061., 431011.}, {12., 431011., 433071.}, {13., 433071., 
  431011.}, {14., 431011., 434011.}, {15., 434011., 431011.}, {16., 
  431011., 434031.}, {17., 434031., 431011.}, {18., 431011., 
  434041.}, {19., 434041., 431011.}};

Comment: FilteredIndexedSOCList = 
 Union[IndexedSOCList, 
  SameTest -> (Sort[#1[[2]]] === Sort[#2[[2]]] &)]

Comment: "Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Sort[431011.`"                                                                                                   "Further output  will be suppressed during this calculation"

Comment: The list in your comment is different in structure than the list in your post. To match your post, it would need to be `IndexedSOCList={{1., {431011., 431011.}}, {2., {431011., 433011.}}, {3., {433011., 431011.}}, ... `, in which case my code works (if I understood what you were after, of course). If the format in your comment is the actual correct one, then try `Union[IndexedSOCList, 
 SameTest -> (Sort[#1[[2 ;; 3]]] === Sort[#2[[2 ;; 3]]] &)]`.

Comment: You are right! I apologize.  How can it be done with a list in  the second format

Comment: I added that to the last comment.

Comment: Yes, indeed; your code works like a charm!  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use `Union` with a custom `SameTest`:

```
Union[IndexedSOCList, SameTest -> (Sort[#1[[2 ;; 3]]] === Sort[#2[[2 ;; 3]]] &)]
```

Alternatively, use `DeleteDuplicatesBy`:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[IndexedSOCList, Sort[#[[2 ;; 3]]] &]
```